# ETH sent default on BASE network sent on wrong network

Tags: cpp-ethereum, network

Sent 690$ of ETH to bovata from coin base it went out default base network instead of ETH network. Can anyone help me
Recover it?

Comment: https://basescan.org/tx/0x78766a9852945fc52e255d5d07b1175733d4c15cc139893b624a9d7ee10cb4e0

Answer (score 1):

There's on way to revert a transaction once it's executed, so your only chance is to access the same address on the different network.

If you have the private key for the receiving address, you can just create the same address in the other network with the same private key. The assets will be waiting for you at that address.

If you don't have control over the receiving address, you have to find out who does and try to get them to return the assets.

Comment: Thank you lauri

Comment: Would I have to get the private key from Coinbase ? Or from the recipient (bovata)

Comment: Nobody is going to give you their private key. If you don't have direct control over the recipient address, you have to ask the recipient to return your assets.